# Auto highlight when using powershell-extensions tag?

Tags: discussion

I have this suggestion to automatically highlight the code snippets to `<!-- language: lang-powershell -->` when using [powershell-extensions](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell-extensions) or [powershell](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't make it happen automatically I'm afraid. It's up to the individual user and/or community editors to add in these tags.

Would be nice though :-)

See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285298/81631

*EDIT*

I did some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

I am wrong. SO can do auto highlighting based on language tag. But we don't really tag for languages here, so all highlighting is a manual process.

That said; Power Shell isn't supported for auto tagging on SO - which I would guess is why it isn't here either.